# Laravel Redirect::action() fallback?

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

As the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects) says the function `Redirect::action()` receives a string which is separated into 2 parts by the symbol `@`

1. The controller name
2. The method name

e.g. `Redirect::action('MyController@myFunction')`

I've recently tried to give the function an input: `Redirect::action('someRouteName')` and see what's gonna happen. Surprisingly it didn't return with an error but actually made the link just as if I was using the `Redirect::route()` function (I had a route named as `someRouteName`).

Does the function `Redirect::action()` falls back to `Redirect::route()` if the value it gets is invalid? Couldn't find any source that says that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Some insight on it can be seen in sources.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L455

```
/**
 * Get the URL to a controller action.
 *
 * @param  string  $action
 * @param  mixed   $parameters
 * @param  bool    $absolute
 * @return string
 */
public function action($action, $parameters = array(), $absolute = true)
{
    return $this->route($action, $parameters, $absolute, $this->routes->getByAction($action));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find it documented, the snippet just makes it clear ;)